# Seeking GIS Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, status-completed, statistics

I am looking to pull information from this site (GIS Stack Exchange) via an API, similarly to the API that exists for Stack Exchange  https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

My goal is to be able to access the following information:

- Number of views per question
- Count per tag description
- Number of up votes for each question (i.e. popularity of question)
- Ultimately I would like to do this temporally - showing the use of tags or questions over time (i.e. past 5 or 10 years)

I did a quick pull from the Stack Exchange API on the term GIS and there were minimal returns.

Is the GIS Stack Exchange information accessible from the Stack Exchange API?

Comment: Like https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=gis ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option to get data listed in your question is the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (SEDE). It is updated weekly.

More info about SEDE is available [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/help).